# How can i read a text file of lists and append into list of lists?

Tags: python, list

My current code looks something like this:

```
a_list = []
with open("lists.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a_list.append(line)
```

When i print the a_list, list i get this:

```
[['["David", 45, 102, 7.5, 0, 17.5, 106, 139, 8.5]', ''],
 [['["Phil", 45, 102, 7.5, 0, 17.5, 106, 139, 8.5]', '']...
```

What i am looking to get is this:

```
[["David", 45, 102, 7.5, 0, 17.5, 106, 139, 8.5], 
 ["Phil", 45, 102, 7.5, 0, 17.5, 106, 139, 8.5]]
```

Programming language is python
Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you paste a couple of lines from your `lists.txt`? I just want to see how the data is contained.

Comment: ["David", 45, 102, 7.5, 0, 17.5, 106, 139, 8.5]
["Phil", 47.5, 110, 7.8, 370, 17.5, 105, 122, 8.6]
["Andre", 47.8, 101, 7.9, 97, 17.2, 95, 114, 8.4]
["Chip", 47.6, 95, 7.8, 158, 17.3, 111, 122, 8.5]
["Loki", 47.8, 100, 7.9, 218, 17.1, 135, 93, 8.4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we write anything in to the text file, its data structure get converted in to string type only. 
So, when we load/open our text file and wish to retain its original data structure in which we wrote/stored in our file, we need to use **ast Module** / ****liter_eval inbuilt function in ast** ** .

```
from ast import literal_eval
file_object= open('lists.txt')
output_list=[]
for line in file_object:
    line=line.strip('\r\n')
    output_list.append(literal_eval(line))
print output_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a package called ast. Try the following after your code snippet:

```
import ast

final_list = [ast.literal_eval(j) for i in a_list for j in i]
```

Your txt file has converted the list into a str , the above mentioned package does somewhat of an exexute. Feel free to read up when you have time.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I get an error with that line. line 8, in <module>
    final_list = [ast.literal_eval(j) for i in a_list for j in i]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a file containing many JSON documents, one per line. You can read it with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

a_list = []
with open("lists.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a_list.append(json.loads(line))
```

**Why not the `ast` module?** No reason in *this case*, but `ast` loads *Python literals* (literals can represent strings, numbers, dicts and tuples).

But [JSON](http://json.org/) is another thing entirely, and while superficially both look similar, the differences will be very notable with more complex data (such as Unicode).